# Remove my personal name on app in Apple App Store / TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

As a freelancer, I've developed an iOS app for a client.  I've submitted it to Apple via my personal developer account, and it's now ready for beta testing. But the emails sent by TestFlight have my personal name on them, which neither I nor my client is happy with.  How can I change this to use my client's name instead?

Comment: Your client will need to sign up for a corporate developer program membership and you would need to transfer the app to that program membership (or recompile the app and submit it through that membership with a different bundle id)

Comment: @Paulw11 - there's no provision for a developer working as a freelancer for multple clients without creating a separate account for each app?

Comment: Of course you can publish multiple apps, but the apps are going to be published under your name.  Apps are always published under the legal name of the member; either their personal name if it is a personal membership or the company name if it is a company account

Comment: @Paulw11 is right.